# live-server vs code extension opens tabs at 75% zoom in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, vscode-extensions, zoom-sdk, liveserver

I recently realized that when I use live-server in vs code, the tab that it opens defaults to a 75% zoom in chrome. I have unknowingly designed about 10 different projects for the Odin Project at 75% zoom, and at 100% they are all messed up. My default zoom setting in chrome is 100%. This 75% problem only happens when I open a tab via the live-server extension in vs code. Opening a new tab directly in chrome opens at 100% zoom. I couldn't find anything related to zoom in the settings.json file in vs code and I didn't see anything in the settings page for the live-server extension. The issue is that live-server is opening tabs at 75% zoom. I don't know why and I don't want to have to manually adjust the zoom every time I use live-server. Thank you for any help at all.

Comment: Did you try setting the following values in your vs code settings.
`"liveServer.settings.AdvanceCustomBrowserCmdLine": null,`
`"liveServer.settings.ChromeDebuggingAttachment": false,`
`"liveServer.settings.CustomBrowser": null`

Comment: I have not tried this, thank you for your reply. I will let you know if this works when I'm at my computer later. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry for the delay, this appears to have worked. Tabs are opening at 100% zoom via live-server now. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Reset the default settings of Live Server by adding the following settings to your VS Code settings file.

```json
"liveServer.settings.AdvanceCustomBrowserCmdLine": null,
"liveServer.settings.ChromeDebuggingAttachment": false,
"liveServer.settings.CustomBrowser": null
```

Changing to the deafault setting should open the browser in the default mode.

> Adding my comment that worked for the OP as the answer to this
> question.